# I am trying to display data in following format?

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json like below structure which i want to reduce to the table. All the ID should be in table header and version and corresponding status in the table columns.

```
[
  {
    "Version": "989.999",
    "clue": [
      {
        "Id": 280,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"        
      },
      {
        "Id": 280,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      },
      {
        "Id": 346,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      },
      {
        "Id": 346,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      }
    ]    
  },
  {
    "Version": "989.131.1",
    "clue": [
      {
        "Id": 280,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"        
      },
      {
        "Id": 346,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      }
    ]    
  },
  {
    "Version": "989.131",
    "clue": [
      {
        "Id": 280,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"        
      },
      {
        "Id": 346,
        "Status": "QUEUED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      }
    ]    
  },

  {
    "Version": "989.122",
    "clue": [
      {
        "Id": 192,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-890-FF"        
      },
      {
        "Id": 192,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-891-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 192,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-893-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 192,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-895-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 197,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      },
      {
        "Id": 348,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-890-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 348,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-891-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 348,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-893-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 348,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-895-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 349,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-AA-99-22-11"
      },
      {
        "Id": 350,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-883-FF
      },
      {
        "Id": 350,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-897-FF
      },
      {
        "Id": 352,
        "Status": "CANCELLED",
        "value": "XXXX-400-FF"
      },
      {
        "Id": 352,
        "Status": "NEW FAILURE",
        "value": "XXXX-875-FF"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in HTML table like -  I want to reduce the table header columns and corresponding . I am new to javascript.

```
    +--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 ID |  XXXXXXXXXX  |   280   |   280   |   346   |   346   |  192       | 192      .... 352
    +--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    | Version      |         |         |         |         |
    | 989.999      | QUEUED  | QUEUED  | QUEUED  | QUEUED  |  -         | -        ..... -
    | 989.131.1    | QUEUED  | -       | QUEUED  | -       |  -         |   -      ..... -
    | 989.122      | -       | -       |    -    | -       | CANCELLED | CANCELLED .....  NEW FAILURE
    +--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I tried to do in angular with ng-repeat but no luck to be able to get the table header due to duplicate values and unable to reduce it.

Solution i tried to display the array in template

```
<tbody><tr class="alignCenter" ng-repeat="list in vm.list">
<td>{list.Version}}</td>
<td ng-repeat="arg in list.clue">{{arg.Status}}</td>
</tr>
```

I read like reduce then group by will help in making the header  and to fill corresponding table data.

Comment: Can you please post the code for what you've tried, so we can see where you went wrong and offer solutions?

Comment: thanks @mhodges for trying to help. I just updated the approach but appreciate your direction to solve this.

Comment: Please  show your attempt to actually transform the data.

Comment: is it important that the order of the headers are maintained as you have shown in your illustrated example?

Comment: It can be in ascending order.

Comment: Shouldn't IDs be unique? There are duplicates in some versions.

Comment: @Sasan : Ids can be duplicate.